# Transfering Ribbon XML Made In VBA to VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, vba, vsto, add-in

I'm in the process of moving an addin I created in VBA in Microsoft Excel to VB.NET.  I'm using VSTO to do this.  Since I have quite a lot of XML tags/schema (not sure what word to use to describe the XML) to display buttons, etc on my ribbon, I would like to transfer the XML to a Ribbon template in VB.NET.  Can I do this or do I have to recreate it from scratch?  It's not that big of a deal because it's pretty easy to create additional buttons and everything with the Ribbon template in Visual Studio, but I would rather not have to do that.

Does this make sense?  Any help would be greatly appreciate!

thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly open up the VBA addin with a zip tool and get the raw XML from there.

Then you can open up MyRibbon.xml that was added by VSTO and just paste in the XML from your VBA addin. You can then tweak in the VSTO ribbon designer if you like.

e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx

I did the same rewriting a VBA addin in C#, though I didn't use VSTO but the principles are exactly the same.